# Should I save Wikipedia data to my database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, caching, wikipedia-api, database

I am developing a website which needs Wikipedia data to show on pages. For instance I need a profile page for Barack Obama and I want to get picture of Obama and a short description about who he is.

Anyway, my question is: **should I save the wiki data to my database to use in the next page views of Obama or should I always get the data from wiki**? There are going to be many pages like this and I want my website to run smoothly in terms of performance, like page rendering latency or sth.

What is the appropriate approach?

Comment: What if someone edits the wiki page to be a picture of a tree? Who is correct? Wiki or your database?

Comment: So should I just get the data once and save to my database huh ?

Comment: do you need EVERYTHING from wikipedia? its a lot of data.

Comment: Should you? I don't know what your app needs..does it need to be accurate? How much performance are you worried about? What is the target device? Mobile? Laptop? Why don't you just cache data to localstorage?

Comment: Generally loading from wikipedia will be faster than from your server because Wikipedia uses many cdns globally to optimize load speeds for their content and have many servers everywhere. In your database I recommend storing links to the wiki pages/content and serving those links to your clients.

Comment: With pages that get updated frequently then it is best to go to the source rather than storing the snapshot then trying to sync the data later.

Comment: It sounds like you just need info to load from Wikipedia.  Not sure how you are implementing this, but you could have even some scrolling text boxes linked to the wiki url.I would just have everything plugin to your website.  You may not even need a database, because you are linking to them.  The problem with Wikipedia is that it can change instantly and isn't always accurate.  It is instantly updated by users and they can edit things as they wish, with some administration there, but it is real time editing mainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, caching the data, or at least the API requests, at your local webserver will both improve performance and latency.

[Hotlinking images is allowed](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia/technical), but if it gets massive you should consider hosting the most images yourself. Make sure to respect the [API etiquette](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette), and be familar with the [Wikimedia ToS](https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use).